# Android tool to find what's taking space, and delete it?

Tags: internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

Basically, I'm looking for an Android version of [SpaceMonger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/) or [WinDirStat](http://alternativeto.net/software/windirstat/).

Answer (score 5):

[DiskUsage](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&feature=search_result) is what you're looking for. Shows a very nice (zoomable) graph of directories and how much space each one and their files are consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Install [ES FileExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and use the SD Card Analyst tool.